# How to read data from JSON file in ddt Python

Tags: python, python-unittest, ddt

I am using ddt with python.
I have code to read csv which looks like this -

```py
import csv

def getcsvdata(filename):
    rows = []
    datafile = open(filename, "r")
    reader = csv.reader(datafile)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)
    return rows
```

How can I skip rows from a 'specified number of row' to 'specified number of row'?
In above code next (reader) is skipping header row.

Along-with I need to know how to read data from a JSON file?
example JSON file-

```json
{
    {
        "email": "amit@some.com",
        "passowrd": "123@123"
    },
    {
        "email": "tanvi@some.com",
        "passowrd": "123@456"
    },
    {
        "email": "tc.u@some.io",
        "passowrd": "123@789"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need is the library *json*.

Python usually gets shipped with this lib included.

```py
import json

def getJsonData(filepath):
    return json.load(open(filepath))

data = getJsonData("the/file/path.json")
for item in data:
    print(f"email -> {item['email']}")
    print(f"password -> {item['password']}")

# output:
# email -> amit@some.com
# password -> 123@123
# email -> tanvi@some.com
# password -> 123@456
# email -> tc.u@some.io
# password -> 123@789
```

Comment: I am using @file_data(filepath) annotation at test. Returning json.load does not works. I need to return a list.

Comment: @CharuJain could you explain more detailed what exactly you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention about `@file_data` decorator. I am using `@file_data` decorator for test which takes parameter a path of the json file. How decorator will work for given json format.

Comment: What exactly should this decorator do? @CharuJain

Comment: this decorator is used to read data from a json or yml file.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done using json with ddt.

```
[
    {
        "email": "amit@some.com",
        "passowrd": "123@123"
    },
    {
        "email": "tanvi@some.com",
        "passowrd": "123@456"
    },
    {
        "email": "tc.u@some.io",
        "passowrd": "123@789"
    }
]
```

Then write your tests more like this.

```
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, data, unpack, file_data

@ddt
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
"""Some test case """

    @file_data('test.json')
    def test_email_and_username(self, email, password):
        """This tests some stuff"""
        do some assertions here
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use json.

```
import json
json.loads(file object)
```